# Setting value of Row/Partition Key based on other propert

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

Is there a way I can override getter of RowKey property for TableEntity ?

Comment: What language are you using? What have you tried/what does your code look like right now?

Comment: I am using C#. I am trying to implement ITableEntity interface. I am actullay upgrading the AzureStorage Nuget package from 1.7 to the latest one. 
We have classes that implement TableServiceEntity, I am migrating them to implement ITableEntity. We have overriden RowKey property in the older implementation, but can't figure out the way to do with all the changes to AzureStorage

Comment: Please provide what your original code looks like, so we can help accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I would assume that it is possible to use the **new** keyword to override the getter as such:

```
public class Person : TableEntity
{
    public Person(string name, string surname)
        :base(surname, name)
    {

    }

    public new string PartitionKey
    {
        get { return "OhLala" + base.PartitionKey;  }
    }

    public new string RowKey
    {
        get { return "ohMama" + base.RowKey; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Whenever I am using 'new' keyword - I get 400 Bad request.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the snippet to implement the ITableEntity interface

```
public class TestEntity : ITableEntity
{
    private string _rowKey;

    public TestEntity()
    {
        this.Properties = new Dictionary<string, EntityProperty>();
    }

    private IDictionary<string, EntityProperty> Properties { get; set; }
    public void ReadEntity(IDictionary<string, EntityProperty> properties, Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.OperationContext operationContext)
    {
        this.Properties = properties;
    }
    public IDictionary<string, EntityProperty> WriteEntity(Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.OperationContext operationContext)
    {
        return this.Properties;
    }
}
```